# how to properly chain dispatch other actions from effect/action

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I have an action A (intercepted by an side effect), which triggers two other actions after A is finished processing.

Currently, I'm using the `do()` operator from rxjs, something like:

```
this._action$.ofType('TYPE_A').switchMap(action => a_http_call())
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .do(data => setTimeout(() => this._store.dispatch({type: 'TYPE_B'}), 1))
    .do(data => setTimeout(() => this._store.dispatch({type: 'TYPE_C'}), 1))
    //.some()
    //.more()
    //.process()
    //.done()
    ;
```

I use the `setTimeout()` call to (well, hoping) break up the action B from nesting in the middle of A's process. AND, go ahead with A's process after the two `do()`s

Does this practice well? Is there a preferred pattern for triggering other actions?

Comment: You can do it by chain effects, return TYPE_A_COMPLETE, subscribe to TYPE_A_COMPLETE, then return TYPE_B. you can do it with two methods, `let typeB$ = this.actions$.ofType(TYPE_A_COMPLETE)...switchMap(TYPE_B)....` and `let typeC$ = this.actions$.ofType(TYPE_A_COMPLETE)....switchMap(TYPE_C)....`

Comment: hm, seems like it, thx, i'll try it out

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This question was about the old RXJS library, and is no longer valid. The proper way nowadays would most likely using `pipe()`.

---

### The old & obsolete answer just for record.

Found the native rx way [here](https://github.com/ngrx/effects/issues/55), which was pointed out by [this question](https://github.com/ngrx/effects/issues/64)

Comment: the link is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

Using `setTimeout()` won't block the execution thread when processing this Observable created with `this._action$` but if it does something computationally intensive it'll block the thread anyway sometime later when this closure is executed and may cause lags.

However I don't think that `this._store.dispatch` is a blocking call. This means it internally calls some request (or something similar) asynchronously so probably you don't even need to wrap it with `setTimeout()`.

Using `.do()` to cause side effects is possible, just be careful that `.do()` is not the same as `subscribe()` because it might not be called at all until at least one Observer is subscribed (depending on whether you're using "hot" or "cold" Observables).

Comment: `.do()` should do nothing if not subscribed, I do rely on this behavior.